# javascript not work in ui router view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

My project is nodeJs + angularJs + html.

main.html

```
  <html>
     <head>
       <script src="angularJs.js"></script>
       <script src="ui-router.js"></script>
      </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
      <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
 <script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']).config(
           function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider){
               $stateProvider.state('index',{
               url:'/child',
               templateUrl: '/child'
              }
       )});
  </script>
</html>
```

MyProject/routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/child',function(req, res, next) {
res.render('back/childPage', { title: 'Express' });
```

});

MyProject/views/back/childpage.html

```
<div>
    fsdfsfsafsfsa214324234234@@
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">alert(1);</script>
```

MyProject/app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var ejs = require('ejs');
// view engine setup
 app.engine('.html', ejs.__express);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

when I access page(http://localhost:3000/#/child) ,the javascript code in childPage.html will not work.
if I just access nodeJs's router page(http://localhost:3000/child) ,the javascript code work well .

if anybody know that ,please answer to me . if you need more code in my project ,just tell me. thank you.

Comment: when I access page in ui-view nested ,the javascript code in page will not work. if I just access nodeJs's router page ,the javascript code work well  - what do you mean by this? Can you please rewrite the question to make it more understandable? :)

Comment: could you please post the javascript error seen in console.

Comment: I had checked console,but it's nothing to there. javascript code just not excuete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hahahhaahaha ,I get the answer ,just add a controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']).config(
       function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider){
           $stateProvider.state('index',{
           url:'/child',
           templateUrl: '/child'
           controller:function(){
             //you can operate element in childPage.html 
            }
          }
   )});
```

Comment: I think your templateUrl is not correct, but please read tutorials first before posting new questions.

Comment: My English not good  , so I just write code here.   templateUrl point to nodeJs router, It's work well and I had test it;